# EOL String Literal Creating Save Location with webdriver selenium

Tags: python, selenium, date, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So as the title suggests I am trying to accomplish a couple of things in Python 3.

Step 1 - I want to run a script that makes a folder with todays date. I am currently doing that like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

os.mkdir('path/to/Screenshots' + ' ' + today.strftime('%m' + '-' + '%d' + '-' + '%Y'))
```

Step 2 Have webdriver open a chrome window to a link. I am currently doing that like this

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
```

Step 3 Where I am having my issue - I am trying to have webdriver take a screenshot and put it into the folder that I made in step 1. No I would think I do that like this:

```
driver.save_screenshot('path/to/Screenshots' + ' ' + today.strftime('%m' + '-' + '%d' + '-' + '%Y')/image.png')
```

This gives me the error SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal - please help me in understanding what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
driver.save_screenshot('path/to/Screenshots' + ' ' + today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') + '/image.png')
```

---

**Tip:**

If you're using python +3.6, [f-Strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) will help you avoiding this kind of errors by using a cleaner syntax, i.e.:

```
import time
td = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
driver.save_screenshot(f'/path/to/Screenshots/{td}/image.png')
# /path/to/Screenshots/11-13-2019/image.png
```

---

Demo:

https://trinket.io/python3/c25a00b29a

Answer (score 0):

To create a folder with **today's** *date* and save some screenshots that folder you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) based solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import os
  from datetime import date
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  datetoday = date.today()
  os.mkdir(str(datetoday))
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.google.com")
  for i in range(1,5):
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("DaveDoesDev")
      driver.save_screenshot("{}/image{}.png".format(datetoday, i))
  ```
- Output:

  - This program will create a subdirectory with today's date.
  - All the screenshots will be save with different names.
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: date_directory]